# Simulate Apple Firefox in Windows

Tags: windows, macos, firefox

Is there any way, to simulate a Firefox, running on a Mac in Windows?
I have a problem with a website, it only appears in Firefox which is installed on an Apple PC.

In Firefox, installed under Windows it works fine.

Is there any way, to do this?

I would prefer freeware....

Comment: No can do. OS X is only supposed to run on Apple hardware.

Comment: @slhck: Apple is using Intel, and other pretty much standard hardware. And there is a Hackintosh, which runs natively on non-Apple branded PCs.

Comment: The way Firefox is designed it would be very unusual for a site to appear differently under different operating systems, except in regards to certain edge cases such as unstyled form controls and CSS system colours.

Comment: Are you sure the person having the issue is running a new-ish version of Firefox on OS X? I've never before encountered a problem with Firefox on different OSs except if there were different version numbers involved. Could you expand on the actual problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can install OSX on Virtual Box or VMWare they both have support for OSX up to 10.7.x

Answer (score 1):

Try an online browser testing service, which will allow you to preview a site by either a screenshot of your URL in a browser, or give you remote access to a VM of the OS and browser you need.

Some options;

- [BrowserCam](http://www.browsercam.com/)
- [Adobe BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com)